# Как называется шаблон?

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть написанный класс со своим интерфейсом и функционалом. Нужно написать класс, который будет иметь другой функционал, но при этом поддерживать тот же интерфейс доступа.

Вопрос - как называется этот паттерн? Фасад? Или же Декоратор для функционала?

Comment: Полиморфизм?=D

Comment: Это другое)
мне именно нужно подменить один класс другим. Как JDBC работает с БД, но ему все равно что это за БД. Есть обьект, есть методы. и методы для всех одинаковые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фасад. Вопрос можно закрывать)

Comment: возможно это лишнее, но по этим же критериям подходят следующие паттерны: proxy, builder, strategy, state (и многие другие, т.к. практически во всех при реализации используются интерфейсы/абстрактные классы)